# Performance measuring of parallel programing in multicore processors

Tags: performance, multicore, parallelism-amdahl

Hi I am working on computer architecture and I try to understand Amdahl's law for speed-up measuring. Assume we have dual-core processor and execute the program X. We want to increase 3 times speed of program and we buy 8 core processor. In this case how many percents of program X should be parallelized ?

Answer (score 0):

Amount of speedup you can gain from parallelizing a program depend on how much portion of the original program you are able to parallelize. If only 10% of your program is parallelizable, then the most speedup you can achieve is 10%, irrespective to how many processors you are adding to the system.